# Flattening either-or structs into another struct in rust

Tags: rust, struct, enums, flatten, serde

I am trying to create a flexible but specifically-typed struct in rust.  Let's call the struct `Analysis`.  All `Analysis` structs must have fields `name`, `id`, `created`, `modified`.  But there are 3 different kinds of analyses:

```rust
// all enums and struct use the #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, ToSchema)] macro

pub enum AnalysisTypes {
    Chemical,
    Physical,
    Biological,
}
```

Each specific analysis type will have its own specific fields:

```rust
pub struct ChemicalAnalysis {
    statistics: Vec<Statistic>, // doesn't matter what this is exactly
    method_parameters: MethodParameters,
}

pub struct PhysicalAnalysis {
    statistics: Vec<Statistic>,
}

pub struct BiologicalAnalysis {
    sampling_information: Vec<SampleInformation>,
}
```

My goal is to create a struct `Analysis`, that has all the common properties mentioned above, as well as all of the properties from one of the Analysis structs mentioned.  So I create an enum that could be any one of these, and then include it in my struct:

```rust
pub enum AnalysisEnum {
    Chemical(ChemicalAnalysis),
    Physical(PhysicalAnalysis),
    Biological(BiologicalAnalysis),
}

pub struct Analysis {
    name: String,
    id: Uuid,
    created: DateTime<Utc>,
    modified: DateTime<Utc>,
    #[serde(flatten)]     // <------------ flatten values into struct here
    more_fields: AnalysisEnum,
}
```

The `serde(flatten)` *almost* gets me what I want.  When I check this in my OpenAPI docs, the analysis struct will always have the 'common' fields, and will required an entry whose name is either Chemical, Physical, or Biological, with each ones respective fields.

[image]

I want to "de-shell" these properties, and have them flatten directly into the parent struct, rather than require them to be under a named property.  How can I do this?

Additionally, how can I require a property in the parent `Analysis` struct `analysis_type`, that is of type AnalysisEnum, that corresponds specifically to each AnalysisEnum?  For example:

```rust
pub enum AnalysisTypes {
    Chemical,
    Physical,
    Biological,
}

pub struct ChemicalAnalysis {
    analysis_type: AnalysisTypes::Chemical, // this is not correct syntax, errors
    statistics: Vec<Statistic>,
    method_parameters: MethodParameters,
}

pub struct PhysicalAnalysis {
    analysis_type: AnalysisTypes::Physical, // this is not correct syntax, errors
    statistics: Vec<Statistic>,
}

...
```

Forgive me if this is a simple question, or my desired design pattern is not in the spirit of the language.  I am coming from a typescript background, where this can be done easily like so:

```
enum AnalysisTypes {
    Chemical = "Chemical",
    Physical = "Physical",
    Biological = "Biological",
}

interface ChemicalAnalysis {
    analysis_type: AnalysisTypes.Chemical,
    statistics: Statistic[],
    method_parameters: MethodParameters,
}

interface PhysicalAnalysis {
    analysis_type: AnalysisTypes.Physical,
    statistics:Statistic[],
}

interface BiologicalAnalysis {
    analysis_type: AnalysisTypes.Biological,
    sampling_information:SampleInformation[],
}

type Analysis = {
    name: String;
    id: Uuid;
    created: DateTime<Utc>;
    modified: DateTime<Utc>;
} & (ChemicalAnalysis | PhysicalAnalysis | BiologicalAnalysis)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want an internally tagged enum: https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html I'm also thinking you should get rid of the `AnalysisTypes` enum.

Comment: @drewtato that's a bingo.  Exactly what I was looking for!  As a rust newbie I had not heard of that before, but its exactly what I need.  Feel free to write an answer so I can give you upvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called `#[serde(tag = "analysis_type")]` (you can replace `"analysis_type")]" by the name of the field you want to use to store the tag).

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "analysis_type")]
pub enum AnalysisEnum {
    Chemical(ChemicalAnalysis),
    Physical(PhysicalAnalysis),
    Biological(BiologicalAnalysis),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Analysis {
    name: String,
    id: Uuid,
    created: DateTime<Utc>,
    modified: DateTime<Utc>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    more_fields: AnalysisEnum,
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b96161a10911d4d0df70922ae9aa3ef)]

For a full reference of how to represent enums in Serde, see https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html .

Answer (score 0):

Why make five different types (`AnalysisEnum`, `AnalysisType`, `ChemicalAnalysis`, `PhysicalAnalysis`, `BiologicalAnalysis`) when you can make one enum?

```rust
pub enum AnalysisType {
    Chemical {
        statistics: Vec<Statistic>,
        method_parameters: MethodParameters,
    },
    Physical {
        statistics: Vec<Statistic>,
    },
    Biological {
        sampling_information: Vec<SampleInformation>,
    },
}

pub struct Analysis {
    name: String,
    id: Uuid,
    created: DateTime<Utc>,
    modified: DateTime<Utc>,
    spec: AnalysisType,
}
```

> I want to "de-shell" these properties, and have them flatten directly into the parent struct, rather than require them to be under a named property. How can I do this?

Nohow. A sized type is a sized type, it can't change depending on run-time values. You have to make things explicit. I may be wrong about what you actually want though.

> serde

Maybe you just want `tag = "type"`?

> my desired design pattern...

Feels so.